# AWK not able to extract the from field in the maillog

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I am trying to extract some fields from the maillog and it worked fine except this below message when it failed.

```
May 10 07:15:04 chitraak sendmail[8558]: 34ABF4Kb008569: from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>, size=452, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305101115.34ABF4Kb946558@chitraak.abc.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=ip-192-68-1-4.ec2.internal [1.2.3.4]
```

Now when I perform awk it gives me below output

```
cat email | awk '{print $7 " " $NF}'
from=<"dexter [1.2.3.4]
```

Now all email addresses are in format from=abc@xyz.com. Only this message has custom name first and then the email addresses. Can some one tell one unifying regex that will work for above text and rest of the messages as well.

Desired output

```
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>> [1.2.3.4]
```

Since rest of messages does not have spaces in from=<"email"> , that's why my awk commands work for those messages. It fails to extract when there is space involved. Also the regex that will give the above output should also work for rest of messages that have there from field set in format `from=<dexter_noreply@au.edu`

So let's say there are two messages with different formats like below.

```
May 10 07:15:04 chitraak sendmail[8558]: 34ABF4Kb008569: from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>, size=452, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305101115.34ABF4Kb946558@chitraak.abc.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=ip-192-68-1-4.ec2.internal [1.2.3.4]
May 10 07:15:04 chitraak sendmail[8558]: 34ABF4Kb008569: from=<dexter_noreply@au.edu>, size=452, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202305101115.34ABF4Kb946558@chitraak.abc.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=ip-192-68-1-4.ec2.internal [1.2.3.5]
```

The desired output after implementing the regex should be like below

```
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>> [1.2.3.4]
from=<dexter_noreply@au.edu> [1.2.3.4]
```

Is it possible or do I need to capture these as two separate regex ?

Comment: Can you also show us the message where the email doesn't contain the spaces in between ?

Comment: @User123 - I have edited my question to get more clarity if there can be unified regex or does that need to be implemented as two separate regex

Comment: The quoted string in `from=<"dexter prod"...` can probably contain commas and other chars that'd break most/all of the answers you got.

Comment: Thanks to **not** change the rules when you have valid answer. If you forgot something, post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably safe to use the comma to mark the end of the `from=` field:

```bash
awk 'match($0,/from=[^,]*/) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), $NF }'
```

```
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>> [1.2.3.4]
from=<dexter_noreply@au.edu> [1.2.3.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU` `awk`:

no need to pipe `cat | awk`, it's a `UUOC` aka [Useless Use Of Cat](https://archive.vn/9Zcyu)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="from=.*>>"}{print $1}' file
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>
```

See [splitting by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

With `grep`:

```
grep -oE 'from=.*?>>' file
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*(from=.*?>>).*/\1/' file
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>
```

With `Perl`:

```
perl -nE 'say $& if /from=.*?>>/' file
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>
```

Comment: ..thanks for your answer. I have edited my question to get more clarity if there can be unified regex or does that need to be implemented as two separate regex

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With using `awk`'s `match` function please try following solution. Using regex `: from=<"[^>]*>>` to get the exact required output by OP. If a match of regex is Found then printing the matched values by sub-string.

```
awk 'match($0,/: from=<"[^>]*>>/){print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` with `E` option please try following.

```
sed -E 's/^.*: (from=<"[^>]*>>).*$/\1/' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` with regex and using `\K` option to forget the match while printing use following code.

```
grep -oP '^.*: \Kfrom=<"[^>]*>>' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** Using GNU `awk` with its `RS` and `RT` capabilities try following.

```
awk -v RS=': from=<"[^>]*>>' '
RT && split(RT,arr,": "){
  print arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

***5th solution:*** Using simple field separators with your shown samples only.

```
awk -F': |, ' '{print $3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { ORS = sprintf("%.*s\n",_+= ++_,RS = ">>[^\n]+\n")
>                FS = ".+ " (OFS = "from=") }  NF = _'
> ```

---

```
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>
```

a less `regex` more hard-coded in way would be

> ```
> gawk '$(NF = !_ + ($!_ = "from")^_) = $2 ">>"' FS='=|>>.+$' OFS==
> ```

---

```
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This `GNU` `sed` should work for both the cases :

```
sed -E 's/.*(from=.*>.*), size=.* (\[.*\])$/\1/\2/' file
```

Comment: @User123- yeah that gives me the output of both email only. But I want to capture the IP as well along with email id

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you check again now ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*\(from=[^,]*\).* /\1 /' email
from=<"dexter prod" <dexter_noreply@au.edu>> [1.2.3.4]
from=<dexter_noreply@au.edu> [1.2.3.5]
```